# Updating partial JS Api OcoberCMS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to sort table using AJAX

ScheduleC.php

```php
        public function onSort() {

            $groupId = (int)post('groupid');
            $professorId = (int)post('professorid');

            $schedules = Schedule::orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();

            if (($groupId) && ($groupId!='-1')) {
                $this->sortByGroup($groupId, $schedules);
            }

            if (($professorId) && ($professorId!='-1')) {
                $this->sortByProfessor($professorId, $schedules);
            }

            $this->schedule = $this->page['schedule'] = $schedules;
            
            return  $this->page['schedule'];
        }
```

default.php

```html
<div id="schedule-table-container">
    {% partial '@schedule-table' %}
</div>
```

schedule.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sortschedule').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).request('onSort', {         
        update: {'schedulec::schedule-table': '#schedule-table-container'},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            this.success(data);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

The function returns the correct data, but partial is not updated.

The most interesting is that the similar code is working at my another project. Please, help.

Comment: _“Please, help.”_ - with _what_? You completely failed to include _any_ form of problem description here so far! Please go read [ask].

Comment: @CBroe The function returns the correct data, but partial is not updated

Answer (score 2):

The true issue here is because you have the success option being called. [Read more here](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api). So your solution by not returning anything from the server doesn't execute the `success()` option stopping the `ajaxUpdate`.

"Success() | a callback function to execute in case of a successful request. If this option is supplied it overrides the default framework's functionality: the elements are not updated, the `beforeUpdate` event is not triggered, the `ajaxUpdate` and `ajaxUpdateComplete` events are not triggered. The event handler gets 3 arguments: the data object received from the server, the text status string and the jqXHR object. However, you can still call the default framework functionality calling this.success(...) inside your function."

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing return in the handler